# Console needs to output user info

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, console, output

I'm really struggling to execute this program that I am trying to create. I want the user to be able to enter as much information as they want and my program to store it until the user types the word "quit". Once the user types this word I want the program to end and list everything the user entered, in the console. I know that I need to use arrays but I'm not really good at using them.

I have got up to the part where the user can type "quit" and the program will end, but i'm not sure how to get it to list everything in the console.

Here is where I have got  Error to:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Requirement1B {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
String name, entry, exit = "";

System.out.println("Please Enter Your Name");
name = scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("Players Name: " + name);

while (true) {

    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Enter a Game Name, time spent playing the game(in Minutes) and your points"
            + " in this format...\t Game:Time:Points" ); 
    entry = scan.nextLine(); //this is the information I want show on the console once "quit"

    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("If You Are Done type \"quit\" if not press return");
    exit = scan.nextLine();

    if (exit.equals("quit")) {
        break;
    } // This Works. but doesn't show information.

}
```

An example of how i want the information to come out in the console is:

"Users Name" e.g. `StackOverflow`

"------------------------------------"

"Game:Time:points" e.g. "COD:120:12345"

"Game:Time:points" e.g. "FIFA:120:12345"

"Game:Time:points" e.g. "GTA:120:12345"

"Game:Time:points" e.g. "MINECRAFT:120:12345"

Thanks in advance  for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure you need is a list:

```
List<String> games = new ArrayList<>();
String game;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while ((game = in.nextLine()) != null) {
  if (game.equals("quit")) {
    // process 'games' however you want, for example
    for (String g : games) {
      System.out.println(g);
    }
  } else {
    games.add(game);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot and i really appreciate it. Thanks. @Raffaele

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = "";
    String exit = "";
    boolean isInput = true;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    System.out.println("Please Enter a Game Name, time spent playing the game(in Minutes) and your points"
            + " in this format...\t Game:Time:Points");
    System.out.println("If You Are Done type \"quit\" if not press return");

    while (isInput) {
        line = scan.nextLine();
        sb.append(line);
        if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            isInput = false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Your String : " + sb.toString());
}
/*
 * Please Enter a Game Name, time spent playing the game(in Minutes) and
 * your points in this format...    Game:Time:Points If You Are Done type
 * "quit" if not press return Output : Game1: Points Game2: Points2 quit
 * Your String : Game1: PointsGame2: Points2 quit exit loop
 */
```